# Is there anyway to clear the history or record of Ctrl+F in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, history

My laptop lend to someone else for several days, then after I get it back, Every time I search word in webpages open in Chrome using Ctrl+F, there all ready default searching words appear in the search bar, like a *** film name (I don't know how many times he search through these days, maybe thousand times.... ):(

As I often make presentation in public and need to search web-page using hot-key Ctrl+F, to avoid pretty embarrassed case, now I want to clean this history and reset to the default mode. Is there anyway?